# jQuery each() seems stopping after the ninth element

Tags: jquery

There is a strange thing which happening with my script.

Actually, I have a table where I can add/delete rows. When I delete a row, the index of each row is updated. Concretely, if there are 5 rows, if I delete the row 2, the index of the row 3 become 2, the index of the row 4 become 3, etc.

The strange thing is that all works fine, except when there are 10 rows or more. Indeed, with 10 rows, if I delete the nineth row for example, the offset doesn't work. The index of row 10 is still 10, and not 9.

I don't understand what is wrong with my code.

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-without-padding-bot table-bordered table-striped" id="journey-table">
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Place of departure</th>
        <th>Place of arrival</th>
        <th colspan="2">Distance of one trip</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="journeyNumber"><input type="text" class="input-xsmall" value="1" disabled /></td>
        <td class="departurePlace">
            <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-globe"></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="input-large" name="departurePlace[]" placeholder="Place of departure"/>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="arrivalPlace">
            <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-globe"></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="input-large" name="arrivalPlace[]" placeholder="Place of arrival"/>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="oneTripDistance">
            <div class="input-append">
                <input type="text" class="input-mini text-center" name="oneTripDistance[]"/>  
                <span class="add-on">km</span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button class="btn btn-info" id="add-line"><i class="icon-plus"></i> Add another</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#journey-table').on('click', '.delete-line',function() {

    var trIdToDel = $(this).parents("tr:first").find('.journeyNumber input').val();

    $('#journey-table .journeyNumber input').each(function(){

        if ($(this).val() > trIdToDel)
        {
            var newVal = $(this).val()-1;
            $(this).closest('tr').attr('id', newVal);
            $(this).val(newVal);
        }
    });

    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    numJourney = numJourney-1;
    updateTotalRequest();
});

$('#add-line').click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    numJourney = numJourney+1;
    newJourneyLine = $('#journey-table tr:nth-child(2)').clone();
    newJourneyLine.find('.journeyNumber input').attr('value', numJourney);
    newJourneyLine.append('<td><a href="#" class="delete-line"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a></td>');

    $('#journey-table').append(newJourneyLine);
});
```

Comment: try a `console.log($(this))` inside the .each();

Comment: Nice tip, didn't know it. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that you're comparing strings, not integers.

Change

```
if ($(this).val() > trIdToDel)
```

to

```
if (parseInt($(this).val(),10) > parseInt(trIdToDel,10))
```

Because `"10"<"2"` gives `true`.

More generally, you'd better parse all values to avoid having to think too much. `$(this).val()-1` is going to work but `$(this).val()+1` wouldn't.

Comment: Oh god, I would have never thought about it... Thanks a lot! And thanks for the tip.